# .animate stops working once i insert a loop() function in

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I am trying to set my animation on loop but it doesnt seem to be working, i dont know whats wrong with it. At the moment my animation only plays once and then stops,  when i load the page as shown in my gif :

**Javascript**

```
 $(function(){

$("#catogories-1").animate({
            'marginLeft' : "+=65px", 'marginTop' : "-=70px"
        });
 $("#catogories-2").animate({
            'marginLeft' : "-=130px", 'marginTop' : "-=30px"
        });   

 $("#catogories-3").animate ({
            'marginLeft' : "-=128px",'marginTop' : "+=30px"
        });   

  $("#catogories-4").animate ({
            'marginLeft' : "+=64px", 'marginTop' : "+=83px"
        });  

 $("#catogories-5").animate ({
            'marginLeft' : "+=100px", 'marginTop' : "-=23px"
        });  

} loop();  );
```

[image]

**HTML**

```
            <div id="catogories-2">

                <img src="images/Rectangle-1-copy.png">

            </div>

            <div id="catogories-3">

                <img src="images/Rectangle-1-copy-2.png">


            </div>

            <div id="catogories-4">

                <img src="images/Rectangle-1-copy-3.png">


            </div>

            <div id="catogories-5">

                <img src="images/Rectangle-1-copy-4.png">

            </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#catogories-1 {
    width: 133px;
    position:fixed;
    left: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    top: 45%;
    z-index: 5;
}

#catogories-2 {
    width: 133px;
    position:fixed;
    left: 55%;
    right: 45%;
    top: 37%;
    z-index: 4;
}

#catogories-3 {
    width: 133px;
    position:fixed;
    left: 45%;
    right: 55%;
    top: 34%;
    z-index: 4;
}



#catogories-4 {
    width: 133px;
    position:fixed;
    left: 35%;
    right: 65%;
    top: 37%;
    z-index: 5;
}

#catogories-5 {
    width: 133px;
    position:fixed;
    left: 40%;
    right: 60%;
    top: 46%;
    z-index: 6;
}
```

Comment: Can include `html` at Question ?

Comment: oh right i have updated it

Comment: I think its working. Is any issue still there?